# Post Increment Concept in C

Tags: c, operators

Output and Why? As per My knowledge post increment evaluate after the execution of the statement.Here On the left side if logical 'i' value will be 1 or 2?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    if (i++ && (i == 1))
        printf("Yes\n");
    else
        printf("No\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Here On the left side if logical 'i' value will be 1 or 2?

It will be 2 because there is a [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) between the evaluation of left and right operand of logical `&&`.

[c-faq](http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html) defines sequence point as

> A sequence point is a point in time at which the dust has settled and **all side effects which have been seen so far are guaranteed to be complete**.

It means that before evaluating right operand of `&&`, side effect to `i` has  been guaranteed to be done.

Comment: thanks for explanation. I have few more question and i don't wanna create separate topic , so can u help me in that?
if (a == a--)
            printf("TRUE 1\t");
if condition is true or not and why?

Comment: well actually according to arithmetic operator sequence, decrement operator precedes assignment operator, hence first the decrement will happen and then the check would happen. Hence it would be something like `a == (a-1)`.

Comment: then a==a-- and a==--a have no difference?

Comment: @MayurRaikwar: `a==a--` yields undefined behavior.  You're trying to read and modify a variable without an intervening sequence point.

Comment: i checked that in dev cpp,code block and ideone all are giving me the same result. So please explain it to me how it is undefine behaviour

Comment: Search about undefined behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

The result will be *No* because *i* will be incremented immediately after *i++* has been evaluated.
Please try `i++ * i++ * i++`.